# MySQL related tables lookup and rows->columns

Tags: mysql

I've inherited this very large and poorly architected solution and need to write/run some large ungainly queries.

While the query below works and gives me the results that I want, a list of each volunteer that has opted to help, isn't flagged as a test and has an associated user account marked as 'active'. Then with a set of additional columns, one for each of 5 social media platforms (but it could just as easily be a skill list or anything)

```
SELECT v.volunteerid
      , v.firstname
      , v.lastname
      , v.mobile
      , v.phone
      , v.email
      , v.has_smartphone
      , MAX(case vs.socialid when '1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Facebook
      , MAX(case vs.socialid when '2' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Twitter
      , MAX(case vs.socialid when '3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Instagram 
      , MAX(case vs.socialid when '4' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Vine
      , MAX(case vs.socialid when '5' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Google+
FROM wp_cfg_volunteer v
LEFT OUTER JOIN appusers u 
     ON u.volunteerid = v.volunteerid
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_cfg_volunteer_social vs 
     ON vs.volunteerid = v.volunteerid
WHERE v.is_test=0
AND v.will_help=1
AND u.activationstate='Active'
GROUP BY v.volunteerid
```

My question is  this: how can I make the social platform lookup query based, so that instead of hard-coding the `socialid` values and their associated name I can write a query that'd loop through a `wp_cfg_social` table, pulling out the id's and name values?

For bonus points: what's a good resource to get a grip of the in's & outs of mysql queries.

Thanks,
nbsp

Comment: Oh my bad, used wrong formatting...duh.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate Table let's say as you mentioned `wp_cfg_social` with at least two fields, namely, `socialid` and probably `socialname`. And make sure that `socialid` has the values from **1 to 5**. And given that then you could use `INNER JOIN` to display the `socialname` values without having to hard code like:

```
SELECT v.volunteerid
  , v.firstname
  , v.lastname
  , v.mobile
  , v.phone
  , v.email
  , v.has_smartphone
  , s.socialname
FROM wp_cfg_volunteer v
LEFT OUTER JOIN appusers u 
ON u.volunteerid = v.volunteerid
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_cfg_volunteer_social vs 
ON vs.volunteerid = v.volunteerid
INNER JOIN wp_cfg_social s
ON v.socialid = s.socialid
WHERE v.is_test=0
AND v.will_help=1
AND u.activationstate='Active'
GROUP BY v.volunteerid
```

As for your second question regarding mysql queries you could go to the links below:

[Tutorial Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/index.htm) 
  [Dev mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/) as your general reference
  [Normalization](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/database_normalization_basics.html) it's also good to learn normalization as basic to database design

Comment: the wp_cfg_social table contains 3 columns, id (auto increment), social (the platform name) and order (used for display within /admin, can be ignored).

v.socialid isn't a field, the vs is a table that contains multiple entries for each user (ie: there could be user 592 with a socialid of 1, 3 and 5 selected) - sorry i'm probably not describing it well.

no hurry - off home for the day :)